# Send Email Using Spidermon and Amazon SES

Tags: email, scrapy, amazon-ses, spidermon

Hi i am newbie to spidermon, i have read the documentation but did not understand how I can send email with respective Body contents of error message. Can someone provide the code ?
For your reference i would like to add the documentation as well.
https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs, you have to configure the email notifications in your `settings.py` file:

```
SPIDERMON_AWS_ACCESS_KEY = INSERT_AWS_ACCESS_KEY
SPIDERMON_AWS_SECRET_KEY = INSERT_AWS_SECRET_KEY
SPIDERMON_EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'My Crawler Report'  # Or another subject
SPIDERMON_EMAIL_SENDER = 'myemail@gmail.com'  # your email that will send it
SPIDERMON_EMAIL_TO = ['...']  # List of emails that will receive the notification
```

Also make sure in your monitors that you have `SendSESEmail`.

Eg:

```
    monitors_finished_actions = [
        SendSESEmail,
    ]
```

https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actions.html?highlight=email#e-mail-action

Comment: thanks ryan, I found it yesterday,. could you help in AWS report as well, i could not do the upload i dont know what is end point access policy spidermon.